# How to make an OpenVPN connection over pptp connection in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, openvpn, pptp

I need to connect to my ISP's server using pptp. And then I need to connect to the private network at my office using OpenVPN.

OS: Ubuntu 10.10

How can I make such connection?

Thank you.

Comment: You... I...... *what*?!

Comment: Yeah, there really shouldn't be any problem with using OpenVPN over the PPTP connection.  What is the exact problem you are having?

Comment: Network manager closes an existing connection when I open a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install Openvpn  "Openvpn is different    like pptp" That is not a problem

http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html  This is  good tutorial

PS"Next time pls give us more information abount OS  will  help us this information"

Answer (score 0):

1. Setup PPTP and OpenVPN connections via Network Manager Applet.
2. After connecting to your ISP by PPTP, open a terminal and type:

nmcli con up id "Your OpenVPN Connection Name"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is PPTP works generally inside normal MTU frame size under 1500, typically 1436 MTU. The problem is OpenVPN likes to initially work at 1625 MTU. And if your router does not accept jumbo frames, you will find the OpenVPN circuit will be very unstable. If however you run PPTP directly from your Windows laptop, you will be able to run OpenVPN over the existing established PPTP path with a stable OpenVPN connection.

Comment: however to get around the problem when using a router with no jumbo frames permitted, use an openvpn config that uses tcp and not udp, The tcp windowing will reduce the mtu size to work inside the 1500 barrier